# Showing that the map between fundamental group is surjective

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f : M \to N$ be a map of compact connected oriented $n-$manifolds such that $f∗([M]) =
[N]$. Show that the map $π_1(M) \to π_1(N)$ is surjective. Here $[M]$ denotes the fundamental class.

I have no idea how $f([M])=[N]$ can gurantee the surjectivity of a map.

Comment: The image on $\pi_1$ corresponds to a subgroup, which corresponds to a covering map to $N$. Figure out which covering this is.

Comment: ^ also recall what the degree of a covering map is.